# How to get physical address of GPU memory for DMA? (OpenCL)

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu, dma

I am writing an OpenCL program and I wish to transfer data from a frame grabber to a GPU using DMA. How can I get the physical address of an OpenCL buffer on the GPU to do that?

Comment: In all likelihood, you can't. Depending on what operating system and hardware you are using, there will be host side driver and/or operating system segmentation that will prevent direct access to the GPU memory.

Comment: I am actually using frame grabbers of own design, so the driver is under my control. OS used is Windows or Linux. Still no way of accessing GPU memory address?

Comment: When I was referring to driver, I mean the GPU driver. The host GPU driver (or the display manager in WDDM windows) is actively managing the device memory. Each GPU process gets a context with its own virtualised address space, user space processes doesn't get to see raw memory at all (in fact I am pretty sure all modern GPUs use an onboard TLB which handles address translation inside any given context). NVIDIA have a couple of special drivers hooks for CUDA supporting Inifiband adapters doing DMA to their Telsa cards, but those aren't public AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses! I am insisting a bit as this is a crucial point in my application. My next question is: can I get a Windows virtual address of memory located on GPU and then use it as destination in the memcpy function?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer to that, I don't work with Windows enough to say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

With OpenCL, you cannot get the physical GPU address of a buffer.

However, you can map a region of a buffer directly into host memory, allowing the memory to be copied in and out using standard C/C++ code such as memcpy. See clEnqueueMapBuffer.